# AD8556 instrumentation amplifier not working!

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

I was wondering if someone would be willing to draw a complete schematic to help me get a [AD8556](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8556.pdf) working.

I currently have it set up like this:

[image: schematic]

But the output just sticks at 1.58V. Bias current?

Comment: Please start by adding a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Do you have decoupling caps present? How are you measuring the output? (scope, multimeter?)

Comment: What is the 1st stage gain? What is the 2nd stage gain? What offset value have you programmed? Have you taken into account the 35mV potential offset error on the DAC (gets multiplied by 2nd stage gain)? Have you tried injecting a small signal to see that the output has a signal despite the dc level not being correct?

Comment: Bear of a chip.  I bet there's people out there that would appreciate a clock pin over a Vclamp to avoid that silly pulse-width programming.

Comment: I am highly suspecting the OP to use this chip without any programming. If you don't program it, on reset it will have gain=0 everywhere, and it will not function as an amplifier at all (it will just output some constant voltage whatever you do with the -IN/+IN pins). You need to feed it data to set the various gain/offset values.